# Python flask server won't receive anything when called from ifttt webhook

Tags: python, flask, webhooks, ifttt

So i am pretty new to Python Web servers and was following this question

[How to setup a Raspberry Pi to receive webhooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600445/how-to-setup-a-raspberry-pi-to-receive-webhooks)

to receive a webhook from [Ifttt](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks) in order to control my TV and AC but my server does't show any message from the [Ifttt](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks) server. I have checked that my server is visible from the internet and i can trigger it using a proxy.

Python Code:

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

tv_Power = "irsend SEND_ONCE TV KEY_POWER"
AC_On = "irsend SEND_ONCE AC on on on on on on"
AC_Off = "irsend SEND_ONCE AC off off off off off off off off off off off off off"

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def index():
    return 'Choose Option'

@app.route('/tv_Power',methods=['POST'])
def pow():
    process = subprocess.Popen(tv_Power.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    return 'Changing TV State'

@app.route('/AC_On',methods=['POST'])
def acon():
    process = subprocess.Popen(AC_On.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    return 'Turning AC On'

@app.route('/AC_Off',methods=['POST'])
def acoff():
    process = subprocess.Popen(AC_Off.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
    return 'Turning AC Off'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

[Ifttt webhook](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks) settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All of your routes are defined to be POST.  Perhaps

```
methods=['POST','GET']
```

Comment: Or you may be able to change your webhooks method to use POST

Comment: Do you get a 404?

Comment: Ifttt only says applet successfully executed but my server doesn't show any signs of communication no errors just nothing as if it was never contacted

Comment: Then it's mostlikely you have the wrong port (ssh to raspbery pi and netstat -ltpn to verity) or Ifttt is using some HTTPS as opposed to HTTP.  Can you post how you 'checked that my server is visible from the internet'?

Comment: i made a http request from this https://www.hurl.it/ website and used proxy to visit the my server

Answer (score 0):

Here are some fixes:

1. All of the routes in the code are POST endpoints, weather IFTTT webhook is posting GET request (editable under Method field);
2. Make sure also that the port on which the flask server is running is open and requests from IFTTT not blocked by the router (if you use one).

Check out my article:
[IFTTT, Python, and Flask](https://maplelatte.tech/articles/software/smarter-life-with-ifttt-and-python-flask/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When linking to external sources that you're affiliated with (like the article you linked, which you also wrote), it's important to *disclose* that affiliation. Otherwise your posts might get flagged as spam. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58884642/edit) to add that disclosure in; and while you're at it, copy the relevant content from your article onto your answer. StackOverflow answers are expected to be relatively standalone, and including content from the article will be helpful in case the site goes down.